# Map method is returning undefined values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and i want to get the values < 20, i'm having the new array with that values but is returning undefined values that are the numbers that doesn't qualify that condition.

```
let dataJobs = ['13', '12', '13', '52', '56'];

var valuesUnderT = dataJobs.map((element, index) => {
  if (dataJobs[index] < 20) {
    return element;
  }
});
```

The array that is being returned is:

```
[ '13', '12', '13', undefined, undefined ]
```

Comment: It's because if `dataJobs[index] < 20` is not `true` your function returns `undefined`.

Comment: You are looking for `filter`, not for `map`.

Comment: That's what you asked for - what output were you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Why not take [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns for each element of the array a value.

```js
let dataJobs = ['13', '12', '13', '52', '56'],
    valuesUnderT = dataJobs.filter(v => v < 20)

console.log(valuesUnderT);
```